# How do we use the picture to get the polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

Calculate the solution $p\in \mathbb{P}^4$ off the following interpolatin exercise: 
\begin{align*}&p(0)=2 , \ p'(0)=3, \ p''(0)=1 \\ &p(1)=2, \ p'(1)=0\end{align*}

$$$$

I have done the following:

The polynomial that we are looking for is of the form \begin{equation*}p(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e\end{equation*}

The first two derivatives are \begin{align*}&p'(x)=4ax^3+3bx^2+2cx+d \\ &p''(x)=12ax^2+6bx+2c\end{align*}

Using the given conditions we get the system: 
\begin{align*}\begin{cases}p(0)=2 \\ p'(0)=3 \\ p''(0)=1 \\ p(1)=2 \\ p'(1)=0\end{cases}  \Rightarrow \begin{cases}e=2 \\ d=3 \\ 2c=1 \\ a+b+c+d+e=2 \\ 4a+3b+2c+d=0\end{cases}  \Rightarrow \begin{cases}e=2 \\ d=3 \\ c=\frac{1}{2} \\ b=-10 \\ a=\frac{13}{2}\end{cases}\end{align*}

Therefore we get the polynomial \begin{equation*}p(x)=\frac{13}{2}x^4-10x^3+\frac{1}{2}x^2+3x+2\end{equation*}

$$$$

Now I saw that there is an easier way to solve this using the following picture, but I haven't really understood how we use that. Do you have an idea?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is using the Newton interpolation polynomial (Hermite, see **edit**). $P_n = P_{n-1} + [y_0,...,y_n](x-x_0)...(x-x_{n-1})$. But instead of using the divided differences it uses the derivative. The divided differences is the discrete form of the n-th derivative.

$f[x_{i},\dots ,x_{i}]={\frac  {f^{{(n)}}(x_i )}{n!}}$
Further read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences

**Thus:**
$P_4 = f(x_i)+f'(x_i)(x-x_0)+\frac{f''(x_i)}{2!}(x-x_0)(x-x_1)+\frac{f'''(x_i)}{3!}(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$

Furthermore, the divided differences $[y_0,..,y_n]$ can be expressed in recursion (this may explain the tabular): $$[y_0,...,y_n] = \frac{[y_0,...,y_{n-1}]-[y_1,...,y_n]}{x_0-x_n}$$

I hope it helped :)

**Edit:** this picture uses Hermite interpolation (a modification of Newton interpolation).

**Explaining the first three columns**, they are defined to be (from https://ibb.co/V29yfR6):
$$\bar{x_3}-\bar{x_0}, \bar{x_2}-\bar{x_0}, \bar{x_3}-\bar{x_0}$$
$$\bar{x_3}-\bar{x_1}, \bar{x_2}-\bar{x_1}$$
$$\bar{x_3}-\bar{x_2}$$

These differences are useful if you want to calculate the next divided difference (the last columns).

**PS.** The other columns are constructed by the recursive formula of the divided differences. If there is a 0 over 0 situation, then $\frac{f'}{n!}$ is used. (Both explained in the first part of the answer).

Comment: Ah ok!! And how exactly do we construct the graph that we have on the first picture?

Comment: It seems like: ${\begin{matrix}x_{0}&y_{0}=[y_{0}]&&&\\&&[y_{0},y_{1}]&&\\x_{1}&y_{1}=[y_{1}]&&[y_{0},y_{1},y_{2}]/2&\\&&[y_{1},y_{2}]&&[y_{0},y_{1},y_{2},y_{3}]/6\\x_{2}&y_{2}=[y_{2}]&&[y_{1},y_{2},y_{3}]/2&\\&&[y_{2},y_{3}]&&\\x_{3}&y_{3}=[y_{3}]&&&\\\end{matrix}}$ But I am not sure...

Comment: As I see in some notes, it is relevant to Hermite interpolation. Could you explain to me how $\overline{x}_i$ are defined? Here is an example:  https://ibb.co/V29yfR6 Do you have an idea?

Comment: @MaryStar $\bar{x_i}$ seems to function as $z_i$. With this in mind you may want to look at wikipedia: where $z_i$ is defined to be: $z_{{2i}}=z_{{2i+1}}=x_{i}.$ Further motivation is given on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah so we have $\bar{x}_0=\bar{x}_1=x_0$, $\bar{x}_2=\bar{x}_3=x_1$ !

Comment: @MaryStar indeed!

Comment: Great!! Could also explain to me how the table is defined? What are the first 3 columns?

Comment: @MaryStar It seems like $\Delta x$, I will edit the answer.

Comment: @MaryStar do you understand the full picture now? Can we close this question? (Then click to accept the answer) Happy to help :)

Comment: We have that $y[\bar{x}_0\bar{x}_1]=\frac{y_0^{(1)}}{1!}$. How is $y[\bar{x}_1\bar{x}_2]$ defined?

Comment: $y[\bar{x_1},\bar{x_2}] := \frac{y[\bar{x_2}]-y[\bar{x_1}]}{\bar{x_2}-\bar{x_1}}$

Comment: @MaryStar any questions left? Happy to help

Comment: Ok! And how do we calculate $y[\bar{x}_0\bar{x}_1\bar{x}_2]$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar The same way: $y[\bar{x_0},\bar{x_1},\bar{x_2}] = \frac{y[\bar{x_1},\bar{x_2}]-y[\bar{x_0},\bar{x_1}]}{x_2-x_0}$, is there still something I can elaborate on?

Comment: And what about $y[\bar{x}_0\bar{x}_1\bar{x}_2\bar{x}_3]$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Also calculated from the previous values:  $y[\bar{x_0},\bar{x_1},\bar{x_2},\bar{x_3}] = \frac{y[\bar{x_1},\bar{x_2},\bar{x_3}]-y[\bar{x_0},\bar{x_1},\bar{x_2}]}{x_3-x_0}$,

Comment: So in the numerator is the difference of the previous step and in the denominator it is the difference of the points that are not common?

Comment: @MaryStar Exactly! :) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences, the same in other notation)

Comment: @MaryStar Any questions left?

Answer (score 2):

You may solve this directly with Taylor:

$$p(x) =\sum_{k=0}^4\frac{p^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k$$

Pluggin in the given values you get
$$p(x) = p(0) + p'(0)x + \frac{p''(0)}{2}x^2 + \frac{p^{(3)}(0)}{6}x^3 + \frac{p^{(4)}(0)}{24}x^4 $$ $$= 2 + 3x + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + ax^3+bx^4$$

Now, use the other two conditions to find $a$ and $b$:
$$0 = p'(1) =3+1+3a+4b$$
$$2 = p(1) = 2+3+\frac{1}{2} + a + b$$
$$\Rightarrow a=-10, b=\frac{13}{2}$$

$$\Rightarrow p(x) = 2 + 3x + \frac{1}{2}x^2 -10x^3+\frac{13}{2}x^4$$

Comment: As I see in some notes, it is relevant to Hermite interpolation. Could you explain to me how $\overline{x}_i$ are defined? Here is an example:  https://ibb.co/V29yfR6 Do you have an idea?

Comment: @MaryStar I will check this out. But a bit later during the day. Just got up :-)

Comment: @trancelocation I think we already figured it out, please read the above. But I'd like to read your view :) (maybe it will save you some time)

Comment: @Max : Thanks for letting me know :-) Still busy anyways

Comment: @trancelocation Well I'm intrigued...